# C# WCF Methods OperationContract

Tags: c#, wcf

In WCF, methods or functions that aren't marked as `OperationContract` won't be read or presented as service methods.

But what if I used for example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    void Connect();

    [OperationContract]
    DataTable SelectData(string Proc, SqlParameter[] param);
}
```

Then I used the `Connect` method in the `SelectData` function that it needs a connection provided by the `Connect` method, will it still work?

I'm using the WCF services in a Windows Phone application.

The main question is: should I work only on the classes `IService1`/`Service1`
and put all my functions and methods on, or can I add classes for example Ip1/p1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IService1` interface is your **contract** with the outside world - what the outside world (other code) can see and call.

How you **implement** that internally is totally up to you and doesn't matter to the outside world. So if you need helper methods and classes, just **go ahead** and create and use them!! No harm in doing so!

But that's just the "inside" world of your service implementation - the outside world doesn't know nor care about how this is implemented in detail - the outside world (the code calling your service) ***only*** knows (and cares) about the contract defined by the interface.